# Callback url is mismatch but it is already set for Expo application in Auth0

Tags: auth0

I already set the callback and logout URLs for IOS and Android for my Expo application in Auth0, but it says `it is mismatch, the provided redirect_url is not in the list of allowed callback URLs` when I try to log in by Aut0 on my device.

I set
`com.hknkky.tarifApp.auth0://dev-xxxxxxxxxxxx.us.auth0.com/ios/com.hknkky.tarifApp/callback, com.hknkky.tarifApp.auth0://dev-xxxxxxxxxxxx.us.auth0.com/android/com.hknkky.tarifApp/callback`

any thought?